# Handling a countdown within a database?

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to create a countdown hosted within the database. The countdown will be set at 24 hours based on the individual user account creation date (I already am collecting the creation date). When the countdown reaches zero, an `SQL` query will run to update the tables. And then keep looping 24 hours again, and do the same thing, forever.

Q1: I'm not really sure where to start or what to read. Guidance on this would be a great help.

Q2: Will collecting the h:i:s (hours) on each user, constantly counting down, use **a lot** of my CPU up?

Comment: What type of database are you using?  You'll want to look at triggers most likely.  Store the information about when the account was created in the database and then fire a query changing whatever you  need to.

Comment: Also, there is no reason to constantly count them down.  That would be a total waste of resources.  You will want to just store the start time and use that for comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check the time that is left all the time. Let the DB do it automatically for you.

When creating a user account you can [set up an event in the DB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) 24 hours from that time. It will execute automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A database independent approach is to store an initial alarm_timestamp for 24 hours from "now", and run a scheduler / clock process periodically (every minute, every hour whatever granularity is appropriate). Every clock "tick" run a lightweight query selecting where alarm_timestamp < systimestamp and handled_timestamp is null, and then flip the handled timestamp as a status bit to indicate when the record is handled, and it will not show up next time.

So it would be something like:

```
select * from alarms
  where alarm_triggered_ts is null
  and alarm_timestamp < current_timestamp
```

This avoids repetitive updating of a database timestamp and is typically the way we've implemented auction sites, schedulers, etc. The system clock automatically "updates" on its own.

Your only choice is how to trigger your scheduled "tick" handler. Use a system level scheduler, cron, etc. or use MySQL Event Handler

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html

To improve performance, long-term you can move records out of the alarms table, or set the alarm_timestamp column value to null so it is no longer indexed, to ensure the index stays small.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'm looking into the MySQL Event Handler. I don't think I will be running cron jobs, I want to keep it all MySQL database based. I also edited my question, it will loop the process forever.

Comment: Sure. It isn't uncommon for a scheduler "agent" process to be persistent / active.